# mpd: how to display the total playlist duration

Tags: command-line, mpd, music-player

I want to display the total time of the current [MPD](https://www.musicpd.org/) playlist in [vimus](https://github.com/vimus/vimus), or if that's not possible, at least on the command-line (so I can display it in i3bar). How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it, with the help of a friend. This solution ignores the time already elapsed in the *current song*, but heh, good enough. In the command-line:

```
mpc playlist -f '%time%' | tr ':' ' ' | awk '
    BEGIN {i = 0}
    {i += $1*60 + $2}
    END{
        if (int(i/3600) > 0)
            print int(i/3600) "h " int((i%3600)/60) "m " int(i%60) "s"
        else if (int(i) > 0)
            print int((i%3600)/60) "m " int(i%60) "s"
        else
            print "(empty)"
    }
'
```